# How do you work with the Color Class array?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript

In Google Sheets using Apps Script, I want to read in the font color in many cells, change some values (change colors) in the array, and write them back to the cells.

I have previously used `getFontColors()` and it worked, but it got deprecated so trying to update my script.  I can read in the font colors using `getFontColorObjects()`, I can display them in the execution log (`outRngFontColors.asRgbColor().asHexString()` ), but I don't know how to change the values in the `Color[][]` array (ex. `#000000` to `#ff00ff`).  So how do I do that?  I only want to read the font colors once and then write them back out only once.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();<br>
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();<br>
var outColRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 3);<br>
var outRngFontColors = outColRange.getFontColorObjects();
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please don't use **bold** for code, instead use the formatting options. For details see  [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [Markdown help](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help) (use backticks, `<code>` and `<pre>`)

Answer (score 0):

##### `get` and `set`

In Google Apps Scripts, the prefix `get` is used in many methods that obtain a value or object. In the same way, the prefix `set` is used in many methods that change a value or object.

So, if you already found `getFontColors` returns the values, then it is very likely that the method that changes those values might be `setFontColors`. This could be easily confirmed directly in the Google Apps Script code editor by using the autocomplete feature. Another way is to go to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/ and search for the method. You might also go https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range. This page list all the methods for Class Range from the Spreadsheet Service.

The Google Apps Script code editor will show you help to show the method syntax. This usually includes examples.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFontColorObjects(Color) also includes an example:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var colorAccent1 = SpreadsheetApp.newColor()
    .setThemeColor(SpreadsheetApp.ThemeColorType.ACCENT1)
    .build();
var colorAccent2 = SpreadsheetApp.newColor()
    .setThemeColor(SpreadsheetApp.ThemeColorType.ACCENT2)
    .build();
var colorAccent3 = SpreadsheetApp.newColor()
    .setThemeColor(SpreadsheetApp.ThemeColorType.ACCENT3)
    .build();
var colorAccent4 = SpreadsheetApp.newColor()
    .setThemeColor(SpreadsheetApp.ThemeColorType.ACCENT4)
    .build();

var colors = [
  [colorAccent1, colorAccent2],
  [colorAccent3, colorAccent4]
];

var cell = sheet.getRange("B5:C6");
cell.setFontColorObjects(colors);
```

Comment: Yes, I already had my program working with `getFontColors` and `setFontColors`.  What I was looking for is how to manipulate the `Colors[][]` array when using `getFontColorObjects` and `setFontColorObjects`.  I did neglect to say that I did go into the developers.google.com link before asking this question.